# How can I redirect existing *.phps with this mod_rewrite, too?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

I use the following mod_rewrite to redirect everything to the index.php, but it seems like that if an .php file exists it is opened instead of redirected to the index.php. What should I change to solve this ?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(data/|js/|styles/|robots\.txt) - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

PS: I know there are plenty of examples to redirect .php to something else, but I would like to do it without creating a new RewriteRule if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve with the first 4 lines (they look to be doing what apache would do by default). They are probably what are causing the problem.

Whole block should be

```
RewriteRule ^(data/|js/|styles/|robots\.txt) - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ index.php [NC,L]
```

That will send every except your asset dirs to index.php

If you want an actual http redirect, you need

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php [R]
```

The following is specific to php, if that's all you're interested in

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php index.php [NC,L]
```